# Проблема с миграцией yii

Tags: php, yii2, mongodb

Переношу сайт с одного сервера на другой, сайт на yii2. Вводил следующую последовательность команд.

```
composer install // с этим все хорошо
php yii migrate
```

После ввода последней, консоль выдает ошибки:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mongo.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mongo.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning: Module 'mongodb' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Yii Migration Tool (based on Yii v2.0.12)

Error: could not find driver
Error: Module 'mongodb' already loaded
```

По логике конечно надо скачать php_mongo.dll и поместить по тому пути, но в папке /usr/lib/php/20151012/ лежат всякие разные so файлы, без dll.

В файлах php.ini по адресам /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini и /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini прописал extension=php_mongo.dll.

Если убрать extension=php_mongo.dll то напишет ошибку.

Базу mongodb запустил еще до миграции.

Также в файле /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mongodb.ini прописана одна строчка extension=mongodb.so.

Где скачать правильную версию php_mongo.dll или php_mongo.so и как правильно установить этот драйвер?

UPD: Теперь ошибка только одна:

```
Error: could not find driver
```

К базе подключаюсь так же, как и yii2. Mongo server версии 3.6.2

Comment: dll на linux? Это же виндовая библиотека.

Comment: Понял уже, что ошибся в этом. С этим разобрался, но  теперь при php yii migrate появляется ошибка Error: could not find driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала надо поставить модуль для поддержки mongodb, но это не особо тривиальная задача, но достаточно простая:

1. Поставить исходники PHP `php7.0-dev`.
2. Потом через pecl установить монго: `pecl install mongodb`.
3. В том файле где у вас происходит подключение модуля надо указать `extension = mongo.so;` и никак не `dll`.

Но у вас должен быть установлен pecl.

Не знаю вашей Linux системы, но обычно это делается достаточно просто.

Pecl в свою очередь постарается собрать модуль из исходников и все разработает, только если все необходимые зависимости при сборке будут удовлетворены.

Не понятно только почему именно эта база данных, если вы не можете самостоятельно настроить окружение для работы с этой базой?

Comment: Сделал как сказали, установил php7.0-dev, установил монго через pecl. Ошибку "Module 'mongodb' alredy loaded" удалось убрать, теперь при php yii migrate появляется только Error: could not find driver. Файл mongodb.so лежит здесь /usr/lib/php/20151012/. Подключение extension = mongodb.so я указал. Версия ubuntu 16.04 x86_64. А монго использую, потому что сайт разрабатывал не я, но его нужно перенести и к нему привязана mongo.

Comment: А базу создали? Логин и пароль для созданной базы пользователя указали в настройках? Сама MongoDB запущена вообще?

Comment: Конечно, думаете проблема с подключением? Мне просто кажется я установил что-то не так.

Comment: Надо попробовать клиентом подключиться к локальной базе с теми же параметра что и Yii пытается подключиться, если все в порядке, тогда вопрос к спецам по mongo, я не особый спец по этой БД.

Comment: Если бы у меня был опыт работы с MongoDB, тогда возможно сделал бы боле подробный мануал.